# How to play large chord?

Tags: piano, chords, technique, learning, performance-practice

I am playing Scriabin's Prelude Op. 11 No. 11. (see [IMSLP](http://imslp.org/wiki/24_Preludes,_Op.11_(Scriabin,_Aleksandr)) )

I can reach 10ths fairly comfortably, but I am wondering what to do with chords such as those that appear in m. 14 (C#4-B5-G5). Do I play a subset of notes (and if so which ones?), or roll the chord?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Leaving out notes is rare; usually you would arpeggiate. In fact, when this piece was written, it was common to arpeggiate smaller chords, too. In the below video, you can hear Scriabin himself play Op.11 No.13. He arpeggiates the big chords and some of the others. None of them are notated as such in the score.